# componentDidUpdate does not props fast enough. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onmousemove

I use the event onMouseMove to track my mouse coordinates. When I send these coordinates as props to my child component and use them the prop is already behind on my actual mouse coordinates, but when I try to use them in my main component they are my actual mouse coordinates. I probably made a mistake with componentDidUpdate method. Does anyone know what my mistake is?

Main Component

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  state = {
    XCoord: 0,
    YCoord: 0
  };
  handleMouseMove = e => {
    const XCoord = e.pageX;
    const YCoord = e.pageY;
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      return { XCoord, YCoord };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const follower = this.refs.follower;
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={style}>
        <div onMouseMove={e => this.handleMouseMove(e)} id="test">
          <Head title="" />
          <CreateGlobalStyle />
          {this.props.children}
          <Pointer coords={this.state} />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
class Pointer extends React.Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.positionElement(prevProps.coords.XCoord, prevProps.coords.YCoord);
  }

  positionElement = (x, y) => {
    const mouse = {
      x,
      y
    };
    follower.style.top = mouse.y + "px";
    return (follower.style.left = mouse.x + "px");
  };

  render() {
    const follower = this.refs.follower;

    return (
      <Follower id="follower">
        <Circle id="circle" />
      </Follower>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

From a quick look at your code, it looks like you're using `prevProps` in your `componentDidUpdate` method, and that is why the mouse coordinates in your child component appear to be lagging. You might want to use `this.props` instead of `prevProps` in your `componentDidUpdate` method as shown below:

*Warning: Un-tested code!*

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.positionElement(this.props.coords.XCoord, this.props.coords.YCoord);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

It works better but the coordinates on my props are still running behind on the actual coordinates. 

If I use the function this.positionElement() in my Main component it updates correctly but not in my Child component.

Comment: Maybe you can trying converting the `Pointer` component into a react 
FunctionComponent instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish that, but the most basic way doesn't require using refs or componentDidUpdate. It is possible by just forwarding your mouse position down as props to Pointer component:

Check this codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/l22wm7nrr7), it doesn't lags or delays in rendering the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

Maybe changing your class Pointer to a pure function and using its props directly might speed a little bit!

Here is a snippet to try it out!

```js
function Pointer(props) {
    return (
      <div id="follower" style={{
      left: props.mouse_x,
      top: props.mouse_y
      }}>
        <div id="circle"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }



class Page extends React.Component {
  state = {
    XCoord: 0,
    YCoord: 0
  };
  handleMouseMove = e => {
    const XCoord = e.pageX;
    const YCoord = e.pageY;
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      return { XCoord, YCoord };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onMouseMove={e => this.handleMouseMove(e)} id="test">
          {this.props.children}
          <Pointer 
          mouse_x={this.state.XCoord} 
          mouse_y={this.state.YCoord} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
#test {
  width:100vh;
  height:100vh;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

#circle {
   background-color: red;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}

#follower {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response! It works better but still when I don't make a separate function component and just use a method in my main class it works a lot smoother. Strange problem, but at least it works like this.